# How can I peek into a vector and pop if a condition is met?

Tags: rust

I want to retrieve an element from a vector if a condition on that element is true.

```
fn draw() -> Option<String> {
    let mut v: Vec<String> = vec!["foo".to_string()];
    let t: Option<String>;
    let o = v.last();

    // t and v are actually a fields in a struct
    // so their lifetimes will continue outside of draw().

    match o {
        Some(ref e) => {
            if check(e) {
                t = v.pop();
                t.clone()
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
        None => None,
    }
}

fn check(e: &String) -> bool {
    true
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f10be4f48247026a508f3e6679b533f&version=stable)

This results in the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:12:21
   |
4  |     let o = v.last();
   |             - immutable borrow occurs here
...
12 |                 t = v.pop();
   |                     ^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
20 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

Which I sort of understand, however I don't see a way to end the borrow (without using `clone()`).

Comment: Irrelevant nit: `peek` returns `Option<&String>` so the pattern `Some(ref e)` needlessly makes `e: &&String`. Just write `Some(e)`.

Answer (score 12):

Borrows are lexical, so `v` has the life-time of the whole function. If one can reduce the scope, one can use `last()` and `pop()`. One way to do this is a functional-style map:

```
let mut v: Vec<String> = vec!["foo".to_string()];
if v.last().map_or(false, check) {
    v.pop()
} else {
    None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a match expression that takes `check()` as guard:

```
fn draw() -> Option<String> {
    let mut v: Vec<String> = vec!["foo".to_string()];
    match v.last() {
        Some(e) if check(e) => v.pop(),
        _                   => None,
    }
}

fn check(e: &str) -> bool {
//          ^^^^ better use &str instead of &String here
    true
}
```

*works since the 2015 edition*
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=dbcb4221d736082738a3822d6ef439ef)

Comment: This didn't work back then (pre-NLL) but it's working now. However, I don't see the advantage over the accepted answer.

Comment: @Friedman IMHO its more to the point. One line gets `Some()`, the other `None`.