# Non-Moving Mutable Reference Borrowing in Nested Match Statements

Tags: rust

I'm using Rust to implement a compiler as part of a learning exercise. For parts of the compiler I implement token peeking to perform efficient parser alternation. To do that in Rust, I peek at the token stack then match on the token which results in a nested match statement like below.

```
// Is there an optional type modifier
// Peek at the next token and process it
match tokens.last() {
    Some(token) =>
        match token.clone() {
            lexer::Token::OpenBracket => {
                tokens.pop()
            },
            _ => ()

        },
    None => ()
};
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the appropriate borrow checking logic for passing the `tokens` vector as mutable reference to the innermost scope. I've already tried variations of rebinding `tokens` in the match statement using mutable references, but the compiler still captures `tokens` as an immutable. How do I get a mutable `tokens` reference to the inner most scope in this example?

Comment: @Shepmaster I cannot see why it is a duplicate except because of the title. The answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634634/how-can-i-peek-into-a-vector-and-pop-if-a-condition-is-met is not adapted to this question.

Comment: @Boiethios "adapted to the question" is not really a prerequisite for a question to be a duplicate. If it were, I'd expect there to be an infinite number of "extremely near duplicates" (e.g. "It's not a duplicate because my variable was `foo` and that one was `bar`"). I don't know how much more of a duplicate these could be — the questions have the *exact* same structure - matching on the result of `Vec::last` and trying to mutate the vector.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not matter to clone the token, you can use [`Option::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned)

```
let last = tokens.last().cloned();

if let Some(token) = last {
    match token {
        lexer::Token::OpenBracket => {
            tokens.pop();
        },
        _ => ()
    }
}
```

By cloning the content (and thereby dropping the reference, *i.e.* unborrowing the vector), you can borrow again the vector.

---

If you do not want to clone, you can always do that:

```
let mut must_pop = false;

if let Some(token) = tokens.last() {
    match token {
        lexer::Token::OpenBracket => {
            must_pop = true;
        },
        _ => ()
    }
}
if must_pop {
    tokens.pop();
}
```

This solution is not very "aesthetic", but it works at least.